# Coffee or coffees in this context?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

> In the morning, most sales are coffees and pastries.

*Coffee* can be used as a countable or an uncountable noun. So what should I choose in this sentence?

Comment: What is the context of the statement? Is it about a specific store, a company (like Starbucks), or sales in general?

Comment: I've voted to close this question as POB not so much because I haven't a preference here, but because an unsupported answer starting 'Here I think coffees would be best.' gets over 10 upvotes and an 'accept' flag while one starting 'I think coffee is better than coffees' gets over 20. Admittedly, that answer is supported, but OP could have done the basic research.

Comment: Are you selling countable coffees or the bulk product? If it's a mix, I'd explain this.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If a question should be closed, it should be closed not because of how answers to the question are written up or because of which answer the OP accepts, but because of how the question is written up.

Comment: @JK2 Are you saying that judging that 'answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise' is something all ELU subscribers are inherently totally proficient at? I sometimes give a question a chance, feeling it's a borderline call.... Note that at least two others consider this POB. // FWIW, I disagree with your choice. I'd use 'coffees' as unit sales (cf 'pastries' – virtually forced here, as you say; 'cakes' rather than 'cake'; 'lattes and espressos') – unless, of course, one is talking about bags of beans.

Comment: Note also that 'A is better', 'B is better', and 'A and B may both be used' answers have all been upvoted.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What is POB? // I think 'a/one coffee' and 'two coffees' are used to let the listener know the exact number. Unless you're talking about different kinds of coffees, which isn't the case here, I don't think there's any reason to use the more complicated form 'coffees' instead of 'coffee'. ('Pastries' is a completely different matter for reasons set forth in my answer.)

Comment: But 'I think' and 'I don't think' belong in comments, not answers. I think the opposite (but give no 'answer' as I can't find support for this precise usage).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here I think coffees would be best. Coffee, as an uncountable, refers to the liquid. Coffee in your case isn't that. In your case you are referring to a specific sales item—a cup containing the liquid. Your focus is on selling these individual units.

You could also say "he sells a lot of coffee." But this is really more a figurative usage—a metonymy. Here you are using the contents to represent the items sold—coffee in a cup. You could equally say "he sells a lot of pastry" by the same figure of speech where the pastry component is used to represent the individual items it is used to produce. Or perhaps it is easier to hear in "he sells a lot of cake" and "he sells a lot of cakes." They both really mean the same thing, but by different routes.

So probably coffees, because cups of coffee, which is what you really mean, are discernible, individual units, not the bulk liquid.

Comment: Can you clear the usage of '--'? I've seen them a lot of times, searched about it and wanted to ask a question in this forum. It's ok if you don't because it is a completely different question. If you want, I can post a new question.

Comment: @XenonKfr Fraser would have to confirm, but (from context) the double-hyphen '--' appears to be being used in place of an em-dash '—', to separate clauses in the sentence

Comment: Correct, it is an em dash.

Comment: I would argue that in the "he sells a lot of *(something)*" case, the two are *not* equivalent.  "selling a lot of coffee" means "a large *volume* of coffee" (i.e., maybe somebody bought several gallons of it in one container), whereas "selling a lot of coffees" means "a large *number* of coffees" (that is, number of servings), regardless of how much total volume that was (they might have been tiny cups). This isn't an issue for the original question, though, where the two are pretty much interchangeable in meaning (since it's explicitly about quantity of sales either way).

Comment: Just to satisfy my pedantry: _coffee_ can also refer to beans (whole, ground, or even as instant granules), not just the liquid. If I buy _coffee_, it's typically beans; if I buy _a coffee_ or _coffees_, it will be the liquid in a cup. But that does not change the validity/correctness of your answer.

Comment: I agree with this-- when an uncountable is pluralised, it refers to different *types* of the substance. Modern coffee shops typically sell different roasts, flavors, and other types of coffes, such as lattes, macchiatos, etc. Selling *coffees* would mean you sell dark roasts, light roasts, lattes, cold brews, etc.

Comment: I don't think this answer is entirely accurate -- coffee is often used even when referring to multiple cups of coffee.  "Let's grab coffee this afternoon"  "Want to get coffee with me?"  "We should go to x for coffee today". "I got us some coffee" (eg when bringing a 4 pack of coffee cups into the room)  And so on, these sorts of phrasing obviously implies multiple cups of coffee will be had but the singular is still the more commonly used.  Even if technically correct, pluralizing coffee almost always sounds weird.

Comment: Also I think comparing to pastry is just highlighting how english has all sorts of idiosyncrasies. Multiple pastry will almost always be called 'pastries' while multiple cups of coffee are almost always called 'coffee'.  If someone saw a table filled with pastry and cups of coffee and wanted to comment on the amount most would say something like "that's a lot of pastries and coffee"

Answer (score 23):

I think *coffee* is better than *coffees* although either is possible. But *pastries* cannot be *pastry* because the latter usually means the dough used to make pastries.

In Google News, ["sell coffee"](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1NHXL_koKR818KR818&biw=1280&bih=610&tbm=nws&sxsrf=ALeKk01l4Ez92r8zSFAsBxoCew52pR8LFg%3A1583385883929&ei=G41gXp2qOIL3hwPV3aeABw&q=%22sell%20coffee%22&oq=%22sell%20coffee%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...0.0.0.8800.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.LWM38epCLFk) is much more productive than ["sell coffees"](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1NHXL_koKR818KR818&biw=1280&bih=610&tbm=nws&sxsrf=ALeKk00nJouEhdX27GAaSp_psEiGB8AIuw%3A1583385893116&ei=JY1gXpHiBpH8wQPX3oLwCg&q=%22sell%20coffees%22&oq=%22sell%20coffees%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...36407.36407.0.36806.1.1.0.0.0.0.144.144.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.BD4NWJxtntM).

There's zero hits for "sales are coffees", but there are two hits for "sales are coffee".

> Day said most people don't realize that about half the business's sales are **coffee**. ([source](http://www.derbyinformer.com/news/derby_news/dunkin-donuts-outlet-set-for-north-rock-site/article_48291cfc-c0ed-11e8-8b95-3fa107aca620.html))
>
> Jon said: “The coffee market is huge. On the doorstep side 10% of sales are **coffee**, but in wholesale they account for 80%. ([source](https://www.chroniclelive.co.uk/business/business-news/jon-malton-ringtons-tea-working-10228372))

All in all, the best choice is 'coffee':

> In the morning, most sales are **coffee** and pastries.

Comment: Searching in Google news is a good option.

Comment: At least in the second article, they're referencing bulk, uncountable coffee, so "coffees" would certainly not be applicable there, although it would be a valid usage in the OP's sentence.

Comment: This is the better option imho, because if you're selling just one kind of coffee, using coffees makes no sense to me. I'd expect different beans being sold at the store if you said "We sell coffees." (doesn't really roll off the tongue either) but not when you say "We sell coffee." @XenonKfr if you're talking about a some generic coffee shop, then coffee is the better choice since you don't care about the different kinds but rather the bulk sale figure.

Comment: @JohnHamilton I disagree. If you only sold cherry tarts, you wouldn't be more correct to say, "In the morning, most sales are coffee and pastry." To me that phrasing implies that most sales are of a combined item called "coffee and pastry," not a statement of the type of pastry available. The question "How many coffees do you want?" could be referring to the number of types of coffee (1 medium, and 1 dark) *or* the quantity of cups of coffee (2 large and 1 small). There's a deep context here that I think most speakers would generally accept as imprecise.

Answer (score 4):

I think both forms are acceptable. Using the plural form "coffees" suggests to me that this refers to a variety of types of coffee: traditional "black" coffee, cappuccino, latte, caffè macchiato, etc. This parallels the use of "pastries" to mean a variety of forms of pastry (muffins, crullers, etc.).

It's similar to the distinction between "people" (humans as a general category) and "peoples" (referring to all the different communities).

It would help to see the context of the statement. Is it talking about a specific store, or something more general?

Comment: Mostly this. If you sell generic coffee, I'd say coffee. If you work at starbucks and sell lattes and things as well as generic coffee or some place that has 31 flavors of coffee, I'd say coffees.

Comment: It was about the sales of a particular coffee shop.

Answer (score 1):

"Coffee" used to indicate a cup of coffee is generally used only informally (i.e. "Can I buy you a coffee?" or "We'll have three coffees and a water.").

When speaking of sales, a native speaker (at least in the US) will generally use the collective term "coffee", referring to the liquid, or "cups of coffee" if referring to individual units.