# What is the difference between 'Beer' and 'Beers'? Which is correct?

Tags: grammaticality, american-english, british-english, australian-english, question-tags

Thank you for coming.
I want to ask  you "what is the difference 'Beer' and 'Beers'?"

I had a job creating ads for foreigner. 
So, I made this sentence 
→"50% discount on All Beer."
However I had some questions , like "All beer or All beers?" or "Which is correct grammar?"
When I research that on website, I could find a lot of opinions but some of them were divided among native speakers
I am not Native English speaker.
So, I want to know Which option I should use.

How do you think this "50% discount on All Beer" ?
correct ? or wrong ?
If you have some advice, Please tell me.

Comment: related:  [Coffee or coffees in this context?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/526902/358978)

Comment: Does this question about [Beer and beers](/q/90797) answer the question?

Comment: @AndrewLeach  Yes. I want to know difference between beer and beers. and how to use those. Please tell me.

Comment: Please follow the link that I and @Robusto have included. It seems to both of us that answers there explain the difference.

Comment: @AndrewLeach,@Robusto 
I understand well. Thank you for teaching me carefully!!

Comment: In your question, "50% discount on All Beer" is the non-count usage; compare "50% discount on All Cheese." Whereas "50% discount on All Beers" is a countified usage, different from the "Let's have a few beers tonight" usage focused on in the other question. This usage means "50% discount on All brands of Beer". In this case, the variants mean the same thing and are both fine.

Comment: Why capitalise 'All' and 'Beer'?